# Unable to Load Python 3.6 on Windows 7

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, windows-7-x64, python-3.6

*Fresh install of Python 3.6 on Windows 7.*

I am presented with the following error when attempting to open Python 3.6:

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialise: unable to load the file system codec
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x0000252c (most recent call first):
```

I've tried:

- Setting the Path, PYTHONPATH, and PYTHONHOME variables to the directory where Python 3.6 is installed, but this has **NOT** resolved the issue, despite it being presented as a solution in other threads.
- Reinstalling with the 32 bit version and the same error occurs.
- Running with administrator privileges and the same error occurs.
- Copying the `Python36` folder to my user folder, setting the Path, PYTHONPATH, and PYTHONHOME variables to this new folder but the same error occurs.
- Installing Python 3.6 for all users and just for my user, but the same error occurs.

Comment: Setting `PYTHONPATH` and `PYTHONHOME` is not the solution and actually is generally the problem. `PYTHONPATH` can be used -- carefully -- to add directories to `sys.path`, as long as you're aware it's affecting `sys.path` for every installed interpreter and as long as you never include the installation directory or the "Lib" subdirectory or anything under it. `PYTHONHOME` is only required in special cases. It should never be used for a standard Python installation from python.org.

Comment: In a command prompt, check `where python` to ensure you're running the right version, and check `set PYTHON` to ensure that no Python-specific environment variables are set; if they are, unset them, e.g. run `set PYTHONHOME=` to clear that variable in the current shell.

Comment: Is there an _encodings_ folder (containing a _\_\_init.py\_\__ file) in your _"%PYTHON36\_INSTALL\_DIR%\Lib"_ folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you, erkysun.

Removing all Python related directory paths from my environment `Path`, `PYTHONPATH`, and `PYTHONHOME` variables solved the issues I was experiencing.

For the benefit of anyone else experiencing this issue in the future, I removed these directory paths by:

1. Typing 'env' into my search Windows 7 search bar, and opening 'Edit the system environment variables'
2. Clicking the 'Environment Variables...' button in the bottom right hand corner of the dialogue box which appears
3. Locating `Path`, `PYTHONPATH`, and `PYTHONHOME` and making the appropriate deletions.

Thanks for your help everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Download this file and place under Lib folder in python directory

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/codecs.py